# python - list variable not storing proper result in recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion

I am trying to store all possible parenthesisation of a list through recursion.

Example: `printRange(0,3)`
Answer will be `[[0],[1], [2]], [[0], [1, 2]], [[0, 1], [2]], [[0, 1, 2]]`

I could get a right answer when i tried to print it in side the function.When i try to store the result and print it after i am not getting the desired result.

The code is as follows:

```
res=[]
def printRange(st,size,cans=[]):


    if(st==size):
        res.append([]+cans)
        print cans

    l=[]

    for i in range(st,size):
        l.append(i)
        tmp=[]+cans
        tmp.append(l)
        printRange(i+1,size,[]+tmp)

printRange(0,3)
print res
```

When i run the above code i got:

```
[[0], [1], [2]]

[[0], [1, 2]]

[[0, 1], [2]]

[[0, 1, 2]]

[[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2], [2]], [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2]], [[0, 1, 2], [2]], [[0, 1, 2]]]
```

why res variable is not storing the intended result?

Comment: BTW, the technique used in your code is known as [corecursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corecursion).

Comment: You may also be interested in this related problem  http://stackoverflow.com/a/41310973/4014959

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because `cans` is a list of lists, and those inner lists get mutated. You need to append a deep copy of `cans` to `res`, i.e. a copy that makes copies of the internal lists. You can do that with `deepcopy` from the `copy` module, or just write a simple deepcopy that works for a list of lists.

Here's a repaired version of your code.

```
#from copy import deepcopy

def deepcopy(list2d):
    return [u[:] for u in list2d]

res = []
def printRange(st, size, cans=[]):
    if(st == size):
        res.append(deepcopy(cans))
        print cans

    l = []
    for i in range(st, size):
        l.append(i)
        tmp = [] + cans
        tmp.append(l)
        printRange(i+1, size, tmp)

printRange(0, 4)
print res
```

**output**

```
[[0], [1], [2], [3]]
[[0], [1], [2, 3]]
[[0], [1, 2], [3]]
[[0], [1, 2, 3]]
[[0, 1], [2], [3]]
[[0, 1], [2, 3]]
[[0, 1, 2], [3]]
[[0, 1, 2, 3]]
[[[0], [1], [2], [3]], [[0], [1], [2, 3]], [[0], [1, 2], [3]], [[0], [1, 2, 3]], [[0, 1], [2], [3]], [[0, 1], [2, 3]], [[0, 1, 2], [3]], [[0, 1, 2, 3]]]
```

---

Note that it's generally *not* a good idea to use a list or other mutable object as a default argument because default arguments are assigned when the function is defined, not when it's called, and that can cause surprising behaviour. It doesn't actually cause problems for your code, but it's still a good idea to avoid default mutable args unless you need that "interesting" behaviour, eg so it can be used as a memoization cache, and even then you should use a comment explaining that you're doing it on purpose. :) See [“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) for further details.

---

I would approach this task in a slightly different way, with one of my favourite "toys": a recursive [generator](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html#generators).

```
def brackets(n):
    if n == 0:
        yield [[0]]
    else:
        for seq in brackets(n - 1):
            yield seq + [[n]]
            yield seq[:-1] + [seq[-1] + [n]]

for seq in brackets(3):
    print seq
```

**output**

```
[[0], [1], [2], [3]]
[[0], [1], [2, 3]]
[[0], [1, 2], [3]]
[[0], [1, 2, 3]]
[[0, 1], [2], [3]]
[[0, 1], [2, 3]]
[[0, 1, 2], [3]]
[[0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

If you do actually want a list containing all the results, just pass the generator to the `list` constructor:

```
res = list(brackets(2))
print res
```

**output**

```
[[[0], [1], [2]], [[0], [1, 2]], [[0, 1], [2]], [[0, 1, 2]]]
```